# Image appears above p background, but behind p text in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/96GD7/1/

In IE8, the red `p` background appears *behind* the image, but the `p` text is on top of the image. Somehow the image is stuck between the `p` and its background.

Can anybody tell me why this is happening? It seems to be OK in IE7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try adding the following lines to p style

```
position:relative;
z-index:1000;
```

Comment: Thanks, `position:relative` seems to work by itself - any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

because the img is drawing by svg while the html code read the src of img, then load after draw.as these two dom are not position spacially, then the z-index "auto" will be calculated by the dom load sequence.(besides,this is not only for ie8,but also in ff,chrome,opera...).

to fix,give the p style position:relative.